# Using Campaign Member Object as regular Object?

Tags: standard-objects, campaign, campaign-member

I was using a Custom Object to create Many to Many relationship between Campaign and Contacts to save some information. But there already is Campaign Member object which serve the same purpose. So I am going to create all the custom fields on Campaign Members Object. According to [this link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193871&language=en_US), a Campaign Member's record occupy 1KB of space, while other record occupy at least 2KB of space.

This makes me wonder if there are any features which are not available for Campaign Member object due to which it occupy less space, and maybe due to which I may face problem in crating reports on this object or doing other operations? 
I searched online but did not found any source which discuss limitations of Campaign Member or compare it with other Salesforce's standard and custom Objects. So my basic questions are:

1. What are the limitations of Campaign Member Object?
2. Why Campaign Member's records are 1KB while other's are 2KB minimum?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What are the limitations of Campaign Member Object?

There are no limitations of CampaignMember object, except it has a field (HasResponded) which is auto-derived. More info on this object is [here](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm).

> 2. Why Campaign Member's records are 1KB while other's are 2KB minimum?

Not sure why it is 1KB in the same line why it is 8KB for Campaigns.

Comment: The link seems broken.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it.